# Find a remote position

Tags: hiring-process, new-job, job-search

How do you find a remote full-time employee position? The remote position can be for a position in the same city or one in a different state. Most job descriptions ask for local candidates. Where does one find a job for remote work?

Note: I'm asking about a US remote position, while living in the US. By remote I mean, work for a company and be able to work at your own (at home) office or any location in the US as long as you are getting your work done. With remote work, you do not need to go into the company's office everyday. Other than a few times a year for meetings, you are working outside of the company's offic

Comment: By remote I mean, work for a company and be able to work at your own office or any location in the US as long as you are getting your work done. With remote work, you do not need to go into the company's office everyday.  Other than a few times a year for meetings, you are working outside of the company's office.

Comment: What line of work do you do?  Just wondering as that may narrow down a few choices to my mind.

Comment: I'm a software developer (frontend and backend).

Comment: http://answers.onstartups.com/questions/30934/how-to-find-telecommute-software-jobs

Comment: why dont you try in the companies you had previously worked for.!

Comment: You should look for jobs with companies that have telecommuting or "work from home" options. Generally on job listings these days companies specify if it's an "in office" job or telecommute is possible or you can work from home. If full time is not a big criteria then you can look for freelancing jobs as well.

Comment: How do I find a Job doing X (in this question working remotely) is off topic for this SE.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here are 400 of them: http://www.careerbuilder.com/Jobs/Keyword/Telecommute/

and here

http://www.flexjobs.com/

http://www.flexjobs.com/jobs/web-software-development-programming

Also look for them in smaller posting:
http://www.authenticjobs.com/

http://jobs.37signals.com/

http://careers.stackoverflow.com/jobs

Key words would be telecommute, work-flex, freelance, etc....

Comment: @wwwuser pls take look at https://remote4me.com/
It contains 100% remote jobs for each role and tech stack.
  
Frontend jobs are here: 
https://remote4me.com/remote-frontend-jobs
(Yes, I'm the author of this site)